# Invalid Hook Call - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm really new to JS and React. I get this error:
[Invalid Hook Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LQbJ.png)
when I try to make a component appear and disappear when another component is clicked. This is my code:

```
const RenderList = ({data}) => {
    return data.map((option, index) => {
        return <Item title={option}/>
    });
};

const Header = ({ title, style, press }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={press}>
        <Text  style={style} >{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
)

const RenderItem = ( {item} ) => {
    console.log(styles)

    let dataToShow;
    
    const [listState, setListState] = useState(true);

    if (listState){
        dataToShow = <RenderList data={item.data}/>
    } else {
        dataToShow = <Text/>
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.section}>
            <Header title={item.title} style={styles.header} press={setListState(!listState)}/>
            {dataToShow}
        </View>
)}
```

***EDIT***
RenderItem is used in a flat list element as a function. (From what I understand)

```
const SettingsSection = (props) => {
    const db = props.data;

    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                style={styles.sectionList}
                data={db}
                renderItem={RenderItem}
                keyExtractor={item=>item.title}  
                ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}          
            />            
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I'll edit my question with the information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderItem`, as the name suggests, is a [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), and as such is called directly (like so: `renderItem({item})`), not instantiated as a component (like so: `<RenderItem item={item}/>`).

This translates to React not creating the appropriate rendering "context" for hooks to work. You can make sure your `RenderItem` function is instantiated as a component by using it like this on the render prop:

```
<FlatList 
    style={styles.sectionList}
    data={db}
    renderItem={item => <RenderItem {...item}/>} // see here!
    keyExtractor={item=>item.title}  
    ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}          
/>
```

That way, `RenderItem` is treated as a component and thus can use hooks.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is occurring due to `setListState(!listState)` with press. I suggest you to wrap your state changing method into a function. Because `onPress` accepts only function type but you are giving it a return statement from hooks.

```
const RenderList = ({data}) => {
    return data.map((option, index) => {
        return <Item title={option}/>
    });
};

const Header = ({ title, style, press }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={press}>
        <Text  style={style} >{title}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
)

const RenderItem = ( {item} ) => {
    console.log(styles)

    let dataToShow;
    
    const [listState, setListState] = useState(true);

    if (listState){
        dataToShow = <RenderList data={item.data}/>
    } else {
        dataToShow = <Text/>
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.section}>
            <Header 
                   title={item.title} 
                   style={styles.header}
                   press={()=>{
                       setListState(!listState)
                   }}
             />
            {dataToShow}
        </View>
)}
```