# Invalid hook call when using toast

Tags: reactjs

When using a toast (Chakra UI) inside my action I end up with the `invalid hook call` and looking at their [docs](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) did not tell me what it possibly could've been. I did stumble across this question [Invalid Hook Call - React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051456/invalid-hook-call-react-hooks), but im not sure whether this could be applicable to me(?)

***The code:***

```
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const toast = useToast(); // --> causes the failure
  //fetches, await and promise on this line 
  return redirect("test/completed");
};
```

I call the action from my createBrowserRouter in main.jsx

Comment: Hooks should be defined directly inside the component, not inside an async request callback. You can USE an existing hook value in there, but not define it.

Comment: I figured it was something with the async, but had difficulties confirming this. So basically I should remove the hook from the async function and directly into the component which renders my UI?

Comment: You can't use the hooks inside a normal function, you can use it inside a functional component .. try to call useToast inside main.jsx and trigger it depending on the request response

Comment: @AousMohammad Any examples I can find by any chance, or that you could show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you read about Rules of hooks, I can provide you with a simple example:

```
import { useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const action = () => {
    // action is a normal javascript function we can't use hooks here
    //fetches, await and promise on this line 
    return true;
};
```

then you can go to `main.jsx` any use it there :

```
export const main = () => {
    // main is a functional component so it's okay to use hooks inside it
    const toast = useToast();
    

    // simple example to use toast depending on your action value
    const handleFetch = () => {
        const actionValue = action();
        if(actionValue) {
            toast({
                title: 'toast'
            })
        }
    }
    return( <div>I'm a functional component!</div> );
}
```

Comment: what determines whether something is a functional component and a regular javascript function then? Is it the fact that it should render html to become a functional component?

Comment: Yes functional component should return jsx ( rendering html ) and it has access to react props and hooks while regular function don't